# Creating 1000+ Azure Service Bus sessions

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm developing an application that will generate a number of events for each customer that have to be processed in order. For this I'm thinking of Azure Service Bus sessions and Azure Functions with a Service Bus trigger.

Each day there can be up to 5000 jobs with each requiring 5-6 messages. This would mean 5000 sessions, based on the job ID, being needed each day.

From an Azure perspective would this cause issues with resources, limits, cost, etc?

Is it possible to dispose of any session resources programatically once the final message has been processed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no additional cost associated with message sessions or the number of sessions. As long as you don't use the session state* or ensure the session state is eventually deleted, you shouldn't experience any problems. In terms of volume, the numbers are not very high. For production, if needed, you could always go with the Premium tier.

* more about session state in my [blog post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/sagas-with-azure-service-bus)

Comment: One of the nicest articles on Azure Service bus sessions. Thanks :)